# Reputational risk by association

Tags: publications, ethics, science, medicine

A few years ago, while still an undergraduate student, I published a paper with one of my professors, who is fairly respected in his field (respiratory medicine). Several years have passed and I am no longer in the same field.

Recently, due to the Covid-19 pandemic, he has made several media appearances promoting the use of hydroxychloroquine. Given that several clinical trials have shown there is a lack of evidence supporting the effectiveness of hydroxychloroquine in treating Covid-19, most scientists would regard this view as unscientific.

Given that we have a paper published together, am I facing any reputational risk?

Comment: I would advise you to [change your username](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/85818/how-can-i-change-my-name-on-a-stack-exchange-site). Even with the careful wording, you are more or less implying your coauthor is a crank, and as far as I can tell you have zero homonyms on Google Scholar.

Comment: Your name seems to still be avaiable by clicking on your profile and then on one of the other SE forums.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think it is a non-issue. If you ever see any evidence to the contrary, just disassociate yourself from the professor's recent views. What you did as an undergraduate has nothing to do with what he has recently said or done.

No one has control over what others might do in the future. Only by *now* associating yourself with those views would you share in any condemnation of them. But that would be for your acts, not his.

Relax and be glad that the past is past.